# Debugging Android binary with DDD, got syntax error in Machine Code Window

Tags: android, gdb, domain-driven-design

I'm running `GNU DDD 3.3.12 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`, now I'm trying to debug an android binary with it, so I started it as:

```
ddd --debugger /XX/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb XXX
```

But the machine code view is empty, only an error string says syntax error:

[image]

Any ideas?